# Sort Month in R programming using month.abb

Tags: r

`> df %>% group_by(member_casual,month) %>% summarise(n=n(),avg_ride=mean(ride_duration)) %>% arrange(member_casual,month)`

**Output:**
Groups:   member_casual [2]

|  | member_casual | month | n | avg_ride |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | chr> | dbl | int | dbl |
| 1 | casual | 1 | 18517 | 1823. |
| 2 | casual | 2 | 21414 | 1603. |
| 3 | casual | 3 | 89874 | 1958. |
| 4 | casual | 4 | 126398 | 1772. |
| 5 | casual | 5 | 280387 | 1852. |
| 6 | casual | 6 | 369022 | 1926. |

So, I want to convert numeric month to months abbreviation and sort months.

I used following code to convert the numeric to month abb and resulted output sorted alphabetically; i am expecting result to show JAN,FEB....

`> df %>% group_by(member_casual,month.abb[month]) %>% summarise(n=n(),avg_ride=mean(ride_duration))`

|  | member_casual | month | n | avg_ride |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | chr> | dbl | int | dbl |
| 1 | casual | Apr | 126398 | 1772. |
| 2 | casual | Aug | 358886 | 1759. |
| 3 | casual | Dec | 44891 | 1337. |
| 4 | casual | Feb | 21414 | 1603. |
| 5 | casual | Jan | 18517 | 1823. |
| 6 | casual | Jul | 406013 | 1757. |

if I use arrange() function console throws error  `..2` must be size 24 or 1, not 5667186

can anyone help me out?

--

`structure(list(member_casual = c("casual", "casual", "casual",  "casual", "casual", "casual"), month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), n = c(18517L,  21414L, 89874L, 126398L, 280387L, 369022L), avg_ride = c(1822.94259329265,  1602.65671990287, 1957.52169704253, 1772.21198120223, 1852.36170721182,  1926.09143357307)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",  "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list( member_casual = "casual", .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of",  "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))`

Comment: Provide data with `dput(head(your_data))`.

Comment: @Friede I have updated in the thread... Thank you :)

Comment: When turning your month numbers into months.abb, make them into a factor.

Comment: For example, use this in your code: `mutate(month = factor(month.abb[month], levels = month.abb))`

Comment: @TechCommodities I just tried the above code and it worked.. I need to work a bit to understanding converting the numbers into months.., Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(month) %>%
  mutate(month = month.abb[month])
```

I. e., change order of commands: first `arrange()`, then `mutate()` ("rename"). Alternatively, as @TechCommodities mentioned in a comment, you could do

```
df %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month.abb[month], levels = month.abb)) %>%
  arrange(month)
```